# Map three lists

Tags: python

I have following three lists:

```
paths = ["c:/path/path", "d:/path/path"]
folder_one = ["fol1", "fol2"]
folder_two = ["folder1", "folder2"]
```

How can I map these three lists so the `output` could look like this:

```
("c:/path/path", "fol1")
("c:/path/path", "fol2")
("d:/path/path", "folder1")
("d:/path/path", "folder2")
```

So far I have:

```
somelists = [paths] + [folder_one + folder_two]
for element in itertools.product(*somelists):
    print(element)
```

But it also generate tuple like: `("c:/path/path", "folder1")`

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Iterating over `zip(paths, (folder_one, folder_two))` should give you a starting point.

Comment: What is the expected result? Mapping first list to the first element and so on? Or something else?

Comment: Using a zip is probably the best and most pythonic way to do this. Create a tuple for every input to zip(paths, folder_one, folder_two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give what you want:

```
[f"{p}/{f}" for p, file in zip(paths, (folder_one, folder_two)) for f in file]
>>> ['c:/path/path/fol1',
 'c:/path/path/fol2',
 'd:/path/path/folder1',
 'd:/path/path/folder2']
```

You can split it up in the following parts:

```
zip(paths, (folder_one, folder_two))
```

connect each path to a list of folders (folder_one, folder_two).

Then going over each path and the files in a list:

```
for p, file in zip(paths, (folder_one, folder_two))
```

file is here a list with files.

The last part is iterating over each file in the file list:

```
for f in file
```

EDIT

Sorry I taught that you want the paths, changed for the desired output:

```
[(p,f) for p, file in zip(paths, (folder_one, folder_two)) for f in file]
>>> [('c:/path/path', 'fol1'),
 ('c:/path/path', 'fol2'),
 ('d:/path/path', 'folder1'),
 ('d:/path/path', 'folder2')]
```

Comment: Can you add the output of your code so we can compare it to the output specified by the OP?

Comment: Yes, I have added the output

Answer (score 2):

For your specific output format you can use the following:

```
import itertools
paths = ["c:/path/path", "d:/path/path"]
per_path_folders = [["fol1", "fol2"], ["folder1", "folder2"]]
all_paths = []
for path, folders in zip(paths, per_path_folders):
  all_paths.extend(itertools.product([path], folders))

print(all_paths)
```

Output:

> [('c:/path/path', 'fol1'), ('c:/path/path', 'fol2'), ('d:/path/path', 'folder1'), ('d:/path/path', 'folder2')]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip_longest` ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest))

```
list(itertools.zip_longest(paths, folder_one+folder_two))
```

output -

`[('c:/path/path', 'fol1'), ('d:/path/path', 'fol2'), (None, 'folder1'), (None, 'folder2')]`

Comment: This doesn't look like the output specified.